# Проблема с ассоциативным массивом при работе с cURL

Tags: php, curl

Пытаюсь создать массив с данными, а в браузере пишет `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\...\curpPost.php on line 2` т.е ругается на `[`.

Вот сам код:

```
$post = [
    'op'=>'login',
    'dest'=> 'https://.../',
    'user'=> 'login',
    'passwd'=>'qwerty',
];
```

Comment: версия PHP какая?

Comment: очевидно, что нужен PHP версии >= 5.4

Comment: Если смотреть через cmd то 5.6, а в самом OpenServer 5.3(хз, нормально это или нет). Но с проблемой разобрался, вместо "$post = [" написал "$post = array(". Это значит что у меня все таки версия 5.3? Спасибо за отклик!

Comment: Поставь в openserver версию выше, да и всё. (настройки → модули → php) ........версия у тебя ниже 5.4, да

Comment: Поставил 5.4. Выше не хочет, почему-то, OpenServer просто не запускается после сохранения настроек

Comment: надо значит еще апач поменять на 2.4

Comment: Все заработало. Поставил все по очереди. Спасибо!